# Openssl: Proxy with transparent handshake

Tags: ssl, openssl

I set up client-server connections using mem-BIOs. I was able to send data without socket IO. This was my reference - http://roxlu.com/2014/042/using-openssl-with-memory-bios.

I am trying to design my proxy to do a transparent handshake i.e.

- The version, cipher list, extensions etc that different clients send to my proxy should be the one used in the client-hello towards server.
- Client-auth certificate sent by client, needs to be sent to the sever.

If I directly use SSL_do_hanshake(), I see a separate set of version/cipher-list based on the method I have used to initialize the SSL_CTX_new() is used to the client-hello sent to the sever (by my proxy)

Similarly, I tried passing the client-hello I received to SSL_write(ssl, buf, buf_len) to do the handshake (by calling SSL_set_connect_state(ssl)) and that does not seem to make any difference.

How can I customize the handshake process to re-use some of the parameters that the end points send?

Thanks,
Manju

Comment: When developing a TLS proxy, make sure to read these recommendations: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#appendix-C and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#appendix-D (specifically D.4 for proxies) and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-9 (specifically 9.3)

Comment: Sure, thanks. However, your answer does not give me any insight into how openssl implements this or how I could use openssl. Do you suggest that openssl-users mailing list is a better place to ask this question?